# Allow requests only from specific domains for a Node JS App on Azure

Tags: node.js, azure, web-config

I am building a RESTful node js API server using express which shall communicate only with a specific set of other servers that have dynamic IP addresses. What is the best way to deny access to requests originating from any other domains/servers?

Answer (score 1):

You can list a IPs of your services, and config [IP Security](https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/ipsecurity)  in the `web.config` in your application.

E.G.

```
  <system.webServer>
      <security>
        <ipSecurity allowUnlisted="true">    <!-- this line blocks everybody, except those listed below -->                
           <clear/> <!-- removes all upstream restrictions -->
           <add ipAddress="83.116.19.53"/>   <!-- block one IP  -->                
           <add ipAddress="83.116.119.0" subnetMask="255.255.255.0"/>   <!--block network 83.116.119.0 to 83.116.119.255-->               
        </ipSecurity>
      </security>
   </system.webServer>
```

Otherwise, you can refer to [App Service Environment](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-app-service-environment-intro/).

Please refer to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-security-readme/ for more about Azure App Service Security.

Comment: Thank you for your response. But as I mentioned the servers have dynamic IP addresses. So any way to configure this using domain names instead of IP addresses?